# PostGIS: Problem with SRID conversion

Tags: postgis, srid

I am new in PostGIS and I am trying to convert a geometry field to GeoJSON Lat/Lng for visualization in a map as a layer.

I had a .HSP file that I exported to PostGIS with OpenJump program.

The .prj of .shp is:

```
PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_30N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-3.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

For get the SRID I searched in:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/gcs.html and I got the **4258** code.

But when I execute:

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geo,4258),4326))
```

I get:

```
"{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[526196.6063,4744503.4952],[526155.287,4744194.9938],[526067.3464,4744213.9994],[526088.0997,4744354.9984],[526109.542,4744513.4959],[526196.6063,4744503.4952]]]}"...
```

Which is not a Lat/Lng correct value.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Your code is EPSG:25830 http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-utm-zone-30n/. OpenJUMP can save directly into GeoJSON, though it is creating GeoJSON according to the year 2008 specification.

Comment: @user30184 can you post that as the answer please? Since it seems to have worked for the asker. In PostGIS it would just be: ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geo,25830),4326))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You selected wrong help page that handles geographic coordinate systems. What you have is a projected system (PROJCS) and from the page about projected coordinate systems
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/pcs.html
you can find that the code "25830" stands for ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_30N

> 25830     ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_30N
>
> PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_30N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-3.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

OpenJUMP can also save data directly into GeoJSON but it supports only the original 2008 version of the specification http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html.